# What are the drm-intel kernels in the repo?

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel-graphics

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/

So far it looks like kernels specifically made for intel/integrated Intel GPU drivers? I can't find much on it. They're 5.0, so would it be better for me to use those instead of the current 5.0 kernels at the bottom of the list if I have an Intel CPU with integrated graphics + a discrete card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you have to use the Ubuntu mainline kernel, do not use one from the drm-intel-next directory, unless you are a developer or have a specific need for something that has not yet been merged into the main upstream tree.

It is an unstable working branch specific to DRM/i915, but ultimately gets merged into master linux kernel source tree. See also [here](https://drm.pages.freedesktop.org/maintainer-tools/repositories.html#drm-next).

Comment: So the basic gist of it it is these kernels are the bleeding edge x2 for experimental Intel specific kernels, meant only for active development, aka chockful of bugs. Am I getting that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. In the end that bleeding edge stuff gets merged in the mainstream master. @avisitoritseems

Comment: Not much point in an end-user trying it out without reporting bugs then is it...thanks!